# Amazon EC2 NodeJS server stops itself after 2 days even after using sudo nohup

Tags: node.js, express, amazon-ec2, process, nohup

I have my app running on http://talkwithstranger.com/ and I have deployed it on AWS EC2. I use this command

```
sudo nohup node index.js &
```

To continue running my Node JS server even if I close my terminal and exit my SSH.

However, after 2 days everytime I wake up and I find out that the node server itself stops automatically. I checked the running processes by using

```
ps -ef
```

and my node script is not there.

Google Chrome say site DNS not found, because NodeJS Express is not running of course to serve my html file, but why it stops itself?

What is causing this unexpected shutdown of my server after every 2 days? I have to manually run `nohup` again to run it again.

Does nohup has a time to expire or something ?

Comment: Probably an uncaught exception, possibly caused by a memory leak. Check the bottom of your `nohup.out`

Comment: @Paulpro I checked my nohup.out file,. Does the nohup,out file records errors as well ? How can I track such an uncaught exception because it only happens during late night when I am sleeping. Is there a way to restart NodeJS automatically by pinging the site URL and it no response comes?

Comment: @Paulpro Just found this statement in my nohup,out file which sends the node console output to a file FATAL ERROR: Committing semi space failed. Allocation failed - process out of memory
Could this be a reason ? How to allocate more memory to my Node process?

Comment: That would be the reason, yes. You can use a tool like [forever](https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever) to restart the process if it crashes, but ideally you should fix the problem (memory leak?) that causes the process to run out of memory. You may need to do some profiling to find it.

Comment: Run it as `sudo nohup node index.js > /var/log/server.log &` and see what is the final crash logs look like

Answer (score 16):

You should run node.js using a service / process manager. You can use something basic such as `forever` or `supervisord` but I would actually advise you to take a look at [PM2](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/).

It can do a lot of things - one of them being that it manages your process, makes sure it keeps running, restarts it when it fails, manages the logs, etc. You can also have it autostart when you restart the server.

It becomes really powerful in combination with https://pm2.io, because this enables you to monitor your server's metrics such as CPU and memory remotely and see whether exceptions happened, and much more (such as even remotely updating the software by pulling from git). However, they no longer offer a free plan unfortunately - their plans now start at $79/month, which is a pity. But don't worry, the PM2 application itself is still free and open source, only the monitoring costs money.

Basic usage of PM2:

```
npm install -g pm2
```

...to install PM2.

```
pm2 start my_script.js
```

Starts a script and lets it run in background.

```
pm2 status
```

Shows the status of any running scripts.

```
pm2 restart all
```

Restarts all running scripts.

```
pm2 kill
```

Stops all scripts and completely shuts down the PM2 daemon.

```
pm2 monit
```

Monitors CPU/RAM usage and shows it.

```
pm2 logs
```

Shows the last 20 output and error log lines and starts streaming live logs to the console. The logs are stored in the folder `~/.pm2/logs`.

Using PM2, your script will not stop - at most, it will restart. And if it does you will be able to more easily understand why because you can easily access logs and watch what happenes with memory usage, etc.

#### Extra tips:

To avoid filling up the harddisk with logfiles, I recommend installing the module `pm2-logrotate`:

```
pm2 install pm2-logrotate
```

To automatically launch PM2 with the same script on startup when the server starts, you can first save the current configuration:

```
pm2 save
```

...and then use the following command to install a startup script - follow the instructions displayed, which will be different based on the exact OS you are using:

```
pm2 startup
```

To use PM2 in a more advanced way with multiple processes, custom environment variables, etc., take a look at [ecosystem files](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/application-declaration/).

Comment: Just found this statement in my nohup,out file which sends the node console output to a file FATAL ERROR: Committing semi-space failed. Allocation failed - process out of memory Could this be a reason ? How to allocate more memory to my Node process? Or how to rectify this problem?

Comment: You have to get rid of your memory leak. See https://www.toptal.com/nodejs/debugging-memory-leaks-node-js-applications for example.

Comment: Hey @CherryDT thanks a million for this answer from a couple years ago.  I'm a typical app programmer who dabbles with AWS instances, so, stuff like this really needs to be spelled-out for me and you did it - thanks  :)  You know, I'm running a "Ubuntu" instance on an EC2 (I believe that's like "a server": right?  :) ), I was wondering, it might be better if I run one of the "amazon-linux" instances, their own house flavor?  Would I still be OK **following your instructions if I went with "Amazon Linux" ?**  (The "amazon-linux" option seems to make support easier.)  Thanks again!!

Comment: For any newbies like me reading, I get 2 warnings on the npm install:  npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency /pm2/chokidar/fsevents:
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fsevents@1.2.9

Comment: It should work the same with Amazon Linux. Personally I prefer Ubuntu instances though. It's a matter of taste I guess. (and yes these warnings are perfectly normal.)

Comment: I have updated the post a bit to reflect the situation in 2019.

Comment: The new information you added is totally incredible, thanks @CherryDT

Comment: This is the best explanation, particularly the extra tips. They should paste this to the pm2 docs because theirs are much less clear.

Answer (score 3):

You can try [forever](https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever).Install using the following command.

```
npm install -g forever
```

Then just start forever:

```
forever start index.js
```

Another better option  for production use is `pm2`.You can install `pm2` with below command

```
npm install -g pm2
```

# or

```
yarn global add pm2
```

start server

```
pm2 start index.js
```

The best thing is you can achieve load balancing with pm2(utilize all available CPU)

```
pm2 start index.js -i max
```

For more info, you can visit [pm2](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/pm2-doc-single-page/) documentation page.

Comment: How forever is different from using nohup ??

Comment: In case of forever, it will restart Node in the event of a crash. I think  your node application generating any exception, that's why its getting break.

Comment: After running forever start index.js how can I stop my script if I want to stop it myself?

Comment: `forever stop index.js`

Comment: These are actions for forever: 
   `start`               Start SCRIPT as a daemon
    `stop`               Stop the daemon SCRIPT by Id|Uid|Pid|Index|Script
    `stopall`             Stop all running forever scripts
    `restart`            Restart the daemon SCRIPT
    `restartall`          Restart all running forever scripts
    `list`                List all running forever scripts
    `config`              Lists all forever user configuration
    `set <key> <val>`     Sets the specified forever config <key>
    `clear <key>`         Clears the specified forever config <key>

Comment: you are right bro, my node app is crashing due to exceptions in my node code. but i dont know how to fix them. Can u please help ? here is my question ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37570346/node-js-app-crashing-itself-even-after-using-forever-js/37571484?noredirect=1#comment62633618_37571484