# How to keep svelte server running after closing shell?

Tags: node.js, npm, svelte

I use command `$HOST=123.12.12.12 PORT=8080 nohup npm run start &` to start my svelte project but when I close the shell it exits.

How can I keep my svelte server running in the background when I close the shell?

Cheers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Amazon EC2 NodeJS server stops itself after 2 days even after using sudo nohup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36907766/amazon-ec2-nodejs-server-stops-itself-after-2-days-even-after-using-sudo-nohup)

Comment: @CherryDT thanks for the link, pm2 looks good, but it's not clear to me how I run my command with it. I tried a couple of ways but it didn't work?

Comment: You can set `HOST` and `PORT` in the `env` section of your config file, and if you want to use `npm start` instead of directly specifying the script, you can set the `script` to `npm` and `args` to `start` (in this case it's just important that the `cwd` is set to the script's directory). For example, this is how I run my apps usually: https://gist.github.com/CherryDT/66e43fb9a2c0d7529147b9ba7620d576