# Npm start in background on a server after SSH connection (EC2)

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, npm-start

I have an app that I start with "npm start"
I would like to run it in background.
This app is hosted on aws EC2.

I tried :

- npm start &
  Doesnt work if I disconnect ssh connection
- nohup npm start &
  Same, it fail if I disconnect ssh connection
- I tried to launch with root, or user, doesnt make any difference.
- I also tried forever but I didnt manage to launch with npm start like "forever start npm start" doesnt work

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Amazon EC2 NodeJS server stops itself after 2 days even after using sudo nohup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36907766/amazon-ec2-nodejs-server-stops-itself-after-2-days-even-after-using-sudo-nohup)

Comment: I explained how to use the process manager "PM2" in an answer to the linked question.

Comment: Thanks mate I will take a look and I keep you in touch I didnt know about PM2

Answer (score 1):

You have to use docker.
You will need to read a lot the documentation, because it's complicated to understand if you dont know it : https://docs.docker.com/get-started/

But it does exactly what you want, running app in background in a container.
You can close everything your app will still run.

Enjoy reading !

Answer (score 1):

I will try the docker style next time because im running out of time.
I found a way using :

"screen" command !

Answer (score 1):

Actually the process stop after few hours with screen

Answer (score 0):

You can add a new command (nohup) to your package.json:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "nohup": "nohup vue-cli-service serve &"
  },
```

It should copy your start command, but surround it with nohup and &