# Reverse Proxy Sending 127.0.0.1 as URL, instead of external site-url.com to oauth callback

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, passport.js, reverse-proxy, amazon-lightsail

I am transferring a site from the defunct OpenShift v2, to LightSail on AWS. I have the app up and running on LightSail at `localhost:3333`, forwarded externally. I am able to pull up the site using the `site-url.com`

However, when attempting to login to the app (using Passport Facebook). The callback url is getting set to `127.0.0.1`, instead of the whitelisted (facebook dev) `www.site-url.com`

`https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A3333%2Fauth%2Fwww.site-url.com%2Fauth%2Ffacebook%2Fcallback&scope=email&client_id=XXX`

Relevant login code:

```
const appUrl = "www.site-url.com";
const callbackURL = appUrl + "/auth/facebook/callback";
passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
                clientID: clientID,
                clientSecret: clientSecret,
                callbackURL: callbackURL,
                profileFields: ['id', 'displayName', 'email']
        },

...

app.get('/auth/facebook',
        passport.authenticate('facebook', { scope: ['email'] }));

app.get('/auth/facebook/callback',
        passport.authenticate('facebook',{
          successRedirect: appUrl + '/profile',
          failureRedirect: appUrl + '/?login-failed'}
        ));
```

I added `appUrl`, in an attempt to fix it via server code. However, I have a feeling Apache would be better suited at fixing this.

I setup the Proxy, following [these instructions](https://medium.com/@sharmasha2nk/aws-lightsail-bitnami-nodejs-letsencrypt-cf653573b8a1), and tried all variations of `127.x/site-url.com`

```
ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:3333/
# ProxyPass / http://www.site-url.com/
ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:3333/
# ProxyPassReverse / http://www.site-url.com/
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Try adding `ProxyPreserveHost On` before `ProxyPass`

Comment: Thanks @DusanBajic that was exactly what was needed :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turning on [**PreserveHost**](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypreservehost) solved the issue, Facebook is now receiving the correct callback url

**PreserveHost:**

```
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:3333/
ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:3333/
```

**Apache config:**

`vim /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami-apps-prefix.conf`

Append: `Include "/home/bitnami/conf/httpd-app.conf`

[Start up the app using `screen`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26245942/how-do-i-leave-node-js-server-on-ec2-running-forever) to avoid shutdown when SSH process is killed. Maybe try [nodemon for resiliency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12701259/how-to-make-a-node-js-application-run-permanently)

Thanks, @DusanBajic!