# Lighsail Bitnami MEAN Stack Application Continuous Running

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, mean-stack, amazon-lightsail

I have an MEAN application running on server through Amazon Lightsail. I installed my application in the `/projects` folder and once I ssh onto the server and run node `bin/www` (where my main startup scripts live) the site runs perfectly. The issue comes once I close the ssh shell the site goes down (node stops running). Does lightsail `/` AWS provide any utilities to keep up the server or do I need to manually install a service that keeps it up so I can point a domain at the IP and it is consistently running?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26245942/how-do-i-leave-node-js-server-on-ec2-running-forever has been helpful but still looking into how to restart the screen process on reboot

Comment: I'm not familiar with lightsail but I would recommend looking at one of pm2, forever, nodedemon or strong-pm. I personally use pm2 for any node servers I run on AWS.

Comment: [These instructions](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/startup/) will help with starting the server on boot.